# SmART Gallery extension on LibreOffice not working

Tags: extension, libreoffice

I'm trying to install SmART Gallery extension in LibreOffice but i get the following message:

`(com.sun.star.registry.CannotRegisterImplementationException {{Message="", Context=(com.star.uno.Xinterface)@0}}`

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Install the [libreoffice-java-common [image: Install libreoffice-java-common]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libreoffice-java-common) package.

Clicking the above link will install it in the Software Center. If you prefer to use the Terminal, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-java-common
```

This package and its dependencies (which will be automatically installed with it, if you don't already have them) should fix the problem producing that error.